# How to cancel angular $http request 1.5

Tags: angularjs

I have tried a couple things but can't seem to cancel the http request when the function is called before the previous request is finished.  I'm using 1.5.7 and every time $scope.glsuggested is executed I want to cancel any pending glsuggested.get() requests, tried a few things to reject the $q.defer but no luck.

Here's what I got:

```
// Controller.
export class BudgetController {
  constructor ($scope, $q, $timeout, $log, glbudget, glsuggested) {
    'ngInject';

    $scope.glsuggested = function(cat) {
      var _getsuggested = glsuggested.get(cat);
      _getsuggested.then(function(data) {
        $scope.glproducts = data;
      }, function(error) {
        $scope.budgetdetails = 'error';
        $log.log(error);
      });
    };

  }
}

// Service
export class GlsuggestedService {
  constructor ($http, $q, $rootScope, $log) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$q = $q;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.$log = $log;
  }

  get(category) {

    var defer = this.$q.defer();

    var headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    var req = this.$http({
      method: 'GET',
      headers: headers,
      url: this.$rootScope.apiurl + '/products/recommend/' + category,
      timeout: defer.promise
    });

    var _log = this.$log.log;

    req.success(function(data) {
      _log('success!', data, data.id);
      return defer.resolve(data);
    });

    req.error(function(data) {
      _log('error!', data);
      return defer.reject('error');
    });

    return defer.promise;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `timeout: defer.promise` as one of the options for your $http request, the request won't cancel until `defer.promise` resolves.

So when you put `defer.resolve` in the `req.success` callback, it doesn't make sense because you're basically trying to cancel the $http request after it completes.

Also, `$http.get` actually returns a promise, so there is no need to return its results through another promise. In the `get()` method, you can actually return `req` and handle the results in the `then` callback.

You should probably also make another method in your service that returns `defer.promise` and call that method in your controller.  You can then `resolve` that promise in the controller when you want to cancel the $http request.

Sorry, I know that's a little confusing, but let me know if it makes sense or if you need further explanation.